# How to know data coming from JSON is a Float or an Integer in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3, numbers

I am getting data from Json and displaying it in table view how to check whether the number is float or double or integer in swift 3 if it is float how to get the no.of digits after decimal can anyone help me how to implement this in swift 3 ?

```
                    if specialLoop.attributeCode == "special_price" {
                        let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "$ \((arr.price))")
                        attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
                        let specialPrice = specialLoop.value.replacingOccurrences(of: ".0000", with: "0")
                        print(specialPrice)
                        cell.productPrice.text = "$ \(specialPrice)"
                        cell.specialPriceLabel.isHidden = false
                        cell.specialPriceLabel.attributedText = attributeString
                        break
                     }
                     else {
                        cell.specialPriceLabel.isHidden = true
                        let price = arr.price
                        print(price)
                        cell.productPrice.text = "$ \( (price))0"
                    }
```

Comment: Please add some sample json or code which you are working with

Comment: my `arr.price` may varies like it may get double or float or integer @gurmandeep

Comment: Can you show the `arr` model.

Answer (score 2):

You can use (if let)

```
let data = [String: Any]()

if let value = data["key"] as? Int {

} else if let value = data["key"] as? Float {

} else if let value = data["key"] as? Double {

}
```

Comment: how to use it in model class ?

Answer (score 0):

as describe below, you can find a type of any object (whether custom class or built-in class like - String, Int, etc.).

```
class demo {
    let a: String = ""
}

let demoObj = demo()

print(type(of: demoObj))
```

--> Output: "demo.Type"